# How to start building native tokens on ADA block chain

Tags: token

I saw this blog post from IOHK about building native tokens on ada network. In this particular post apart from command lines a web interface is being discussed but I can find a valid link on that particular post is there some one can give me a good direction in this?

The link which i have saw is below.

https://iohk.io/en/blog/posts/2021/02/18/building-native-tokens-on-cardano-for-pleasure-and-profit/

I have also saw this post as well. https://forum.cardano.org/t/cardano-gui-token-builder/80971/5 .

Atleast If a command line utility is available please share me some step by step instructions for the same.

Eagerly waiting to build token on ADA

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are a few resources I found:

https://developers.cardano.org/docs/native-tokens/minting/

https://docs.cardano.org/native-tokens/getting-started

https://forum.cardano.org/t/an-introduction-to-minting-native-tokens-on-cardano/49734

Comment: I saw thease guides but i am looking for some web based UI i saw the mention for the same on IOHK blog but i was not able to detect any link that directs me to the mentioned UI. I am wondering is there something like that is available or not.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).